# разный формат даты для сервера и для вывода Yii2

Tags: yii2

как в yii2 реализовать подмену дат сказать, нужно чтобы в базу переходила дата формата YYYY-DD-MM, а отображалась при вводе и выводе php:d.M.Y. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В модели

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        [
            'class' => AttributeBehavior::class,
            'value' => function () {
                return date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->date));
            },
            'attributes' => [
                ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => 'date',
                ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => 'date',
            ],
        ],
        [
            'class' => AttributeBehavior::class,
            'value' => function () {
                return date('d.m.Y', strtotime($this->date));
            },
            'attributes' => [
                ActiveRecord::EVENT_AFTER_FIND => 'date',
            ],
        ],
        [
            'class' => AttributeBehavior::class,
            'value' => function () {
                return date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->date2));
            },
            'attributes' => [
                ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => 'date2',
                ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => 'date2',
            ],
        ],
        [
            'class' => AttributeBehavior::class,
            'value' => function () {
                return date('d.m.Y', strtotime($this->date2));
            },
            'attributes' => [
                ActiveRecord::EVENT_AFTER_FIND => 'date2',
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! а как такое же провернуть с несколькими датами сразу

Comment: @CrazyTea Обновил ответ

Comment: @CrazyTea Если вопрос решен, то отметьте галочкой мой ответ